# How can we trigger the next job from current build when it completed

Tags: circleci, circleci-2.0

How can we trigger different project’s job. For example, I have parent job “abc” has repository like “https://github.n.com/user_name/abc”. After building this job successgully, I have to trigger next job “xyz” has repository like “https://github.n.com/user_name/xyz”. Both the project have different repository location.
My question is that how can **abc** project build trigger **xyz** project build.
Thanks,
Rahul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to their docs, you can use the workflow functionality to create a follow up line of build jobs.

https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/#using-the-workflows-functionality

```
version: 2
jobs:
  one:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/ruby:2.4.1
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: echo "A first hello"
      - run: sleep 25
  two:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/ruby:2.4.1
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: echo "A more familiar hi"
      - run: sleep 15
workflows:
  version: 2
  one_and_two:
    jobs:
      - one
      - two
```

As for them being on different repos, I assume you can call `git clone` instead of checkout (in case checkout doesn't support passing the url).

Edit: Some more docs on workflows are available here: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workflows/

Comment: Hi Fabricio20, Thanks for the help